# How to send DE Data to Heroku in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I hope you are understand my unclear question.

As request by customer, We decide that We don't use Mobile Studio.

So, We are send SMS,MMS,LMS Message using Custom Activity in Journey Builder.

Unfortunately, We don't have development knowledge of Custom Activity, and we are trying to figure out how to develop it using AWS Server.

In the meantime, I found the sample code provided by Twilio while searching in Git. So we're currently testing through Heroku.

But, For some reason, that is not working properly than I Thought. that's An error occurs when I activate the Journey Builder.

Let me know what I'm missing.

I certainly appreciate your helping me out.

**I used the following sample source :**

https://github.com/jmaitz/twilio-sfmc

**and The following is a picture of the error content that occurred:**

[image]

Comment: I've changed another sample source. Actually I wanted to make sure it can be data binding. If there are people like me to use the source, the following link, and youtube see how to use, can be inferred.

Comment: https://github.com/trip42/jb-activity, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Naa31iOZFlI&t=933s

Comment: Use this as an example https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit

Comment: @garek007 Thanks for the reply.  that's very helpul.